# Where is the location of developer/globals.php

Tags: 7

It's documented on the drupal website [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/7) but this path does not exist in the drupal installation.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no such file in the codebase. It is documented [separately](https://www.drupal.org/project/documentation). When the API site is built, it combines documentation from code comments in Drupal core and the documentation project.